# Using Mid Rule Actions - bison parser

Tags: parsing, bison

I have following grammar:

```
expr : FUNC '(' expr ')' { ... }
     | FUNC '(' expr ',' expr ')' { ... }
     | expr '+' expr { ... }
     | expr '-' expr { ... }
     | NUM { ... }
```

And I'd like to perform different mid-rule-action on FUNC rule prior to entering the expr, depending on the rule.

Meaning:

```
expr : FUNC { DO_ACTION_1 } '(' expr ')' { ... }
```

or

```
expr : FUNC '(' { DO_ACTION_1 } expr ')' { ... }
```

and in another case:

```
expr : FUNC { DO_ACTION_2 } '(' expr ',' expr ')' { ... }
```

or

```
expr : FUNC '(' { DO_ACTION_2 } expr ',' expr ')' { ... }
```

but I am keep getting reduce/reduce error and $$1 (or $$2 depending on the usage above) will never be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is described in the [bison documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Mid_002dRule-Conflicts.html#Mid_002dRule-Conflicts), as are the mechanisms to resolve the ambiguity.

The ambiguity is due to bison needing  to commit to which of the two rules to apply early in the parsing, and at the stage of your action it cannot tell.

When it has matched:

```
FUNC
```

or

```
FUNC '('
```

or even

```
FUNC '(' expr
```

It could still be one of three syntax rules and thus the action is ambiguous.

To remove the ambiguity you can attach an action to the terminal symbol (either `FUNC` or `'('`) or make a rule for the preamble which contains the action:

```
func : FUNC { DO_ACTION1 } ;
bra : '(' { DO_ACTION1} ;
```

or

```
func_open : FUNC '(' expr { DO_ACTION1 };
expre : func_open | func_open ',' expr | etc
```

Comment: Tompsett - this doesn't solve my problem. I could use similar as you suggested FUNC MIDAC '(' expr ')' and FUNC MIDAC '(' expr ',' expr ')' but that would mean same action for both rules. No conflicts using MIDAC rule. In my question I specified that I need different actions. If rule with func 1 arg is matched I need to perform action A before entering expr. If func 2 args is matched I need to perform action B before entering expr. That's issue here.